# Spring Integration Debug Messages

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am interested to know, is there is a manner to configure the logger os spring integration package in debug mode but without messages (quite large content).

My problem now resides more on understand my configuration than what i have done with the data.

Kind Regards.

Comment: Is your application using logback? You could modify the logging format and leave out `%m`, I think.

Answer (score 0):

See Wire-Tap pattern and Logging Channel Adapter.
The first one will let to to track a message journey through you flow and the second one will let you to configure whatever you want to log with its `logExpression` option.

See docs for more info:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#logging-channel-adapter

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#channel-wiretap

Comment: thanks artem. im quite happy by the wat my the benchmark is reaching a million messages by minute in a map-reduce processing on spring integration. .